# is there a way to print the hidden lwc element

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

In LWC, I have hidden a div tag but I want it to be displayed when I call a window.print() which is not happening. is there any simpler way to print this on a window.print() call ?

The defined div element in lwc

Comment: <div style="margin:0px 10px 20px 10px; border:2px rgb(232,232,232) solid;" class="slds-hidden">hello</div>

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this with CSS:

```
/* main.css */
.custom-print-css-class {
    display:none;
}

/* override styles when printing */
@media print {
  .custom-print-css-class {
        display:block;
  }
}
```

The @media print CSS will only show up when printed.